# Why "d" is undefined in attrTween?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create an interface on d3. I found the arc animation code  (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5100636), and I want to change it a bit (without function arcTween()). 
Here is part of my code:

```
            var arc3 = d3.arc().innerRadius(77).outerRadius(90).startAngle(0);
            var foregroundArc3 = imgs3
              .append('path')
              .attr('d', arc3)
              .attr('stroke', 'white')
              .attr('fill', 'white')
              .style('fill-opacity', 0.5)
              .attr('transform', 'translate('+(146.5)+','+(150.9)+')')
              .datum({endAngle: 0.0628*90, newAngle: 0.0628*270})
              .transition()
              .duration(1500)
              .attrTween('d',  (d) => {
                return (t) => {
                  const interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.newAngle);
                    d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
                    return arc3(d);
                  };
          });
```

But there error: Argument of type '{ endAngle: number; newAng: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefaultArcObject'. Property 'innerRadius' is missing in type '{ endAngle: number; newAng: number; }'.

And in browser's console "d" is undefinded. I tried to find any other working solutions, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this...

```
.attr('d', arc3)
```

... the second argument of `attr`, which is the `arc3` function, get's passed the bound datum, the index and the node's group.

However, there is no bound datum, since in your code the `datum` method comes **after** that.

The simplest solution is just moving the `datum` to before the `.attr('d', arc3)` line:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var arc3 = d3.arc().innerRadius(77).outerRadius(90).startAngle(0);
var foregroundArc3 = svg
  .append('path')
  .datum({
    endAngle: 0.0628 * 90,
    newAngle: 0.0628 * 270
  })
  .attr('d', arc3)
  .attr('fill', 'teal')
  .style('fill-opacity', 0.5)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (146.5) + ',' + (150.9) + ')')
  .transition()
  .duration(1500)
  .attrTween('d', (d) => {
    return (t) => {
      const interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, d.newAngle);
      d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
      return arc3(d);
    };
  });
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But after moving the `datum` an error occurs in               `.attr('d', arc3)` on `arc3`: `Argument of type 'Arc<any, DefaultArcObject>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, { endAngle: number; newAngle: number; }, string | number | boolean>'.

Comment: @Ghosterus as you can see, there is no error in my snippet. So, this is probably another issue, which is unrelated to the issue in your question. It seems to me that you're using typescript; if that is correct, please post a new question with the specific details, and the typescript tag.